# How to create a zonal Shapefile?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3

I need to split a huge raster into smaller parts to be able to process them part per part. (It's not about the size, however the extent is spread across several latitude degrees which is a problem for solar irradiance calculations.) Therefore, I want to extract these parts from the Raster, using zonal Shapefiles.

Is there a tool in ArcGIS to create repeating rectangular shapes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a tool for that called [Create Fishnet](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-fishnet.htm). This tool creates a fishnet of rectangular cells. It's available in all ArcGIS license levels.

Comment: I recently discovered another tool, called Split Raster, which directly fits my needs in this context. However your answer totally fits to the question, thanks a lot!